# Has anyone got the Krypton Lighting Engine working in MonoGame for Windows 8?

Tags: xna, lighting, xna-content-pipeline, monogame, windows-8

I've converted the core of the Krypton Lighting Engine so that it's compatible with Windows 8.

The trouble I'm having when actually using it is that it can't load the `KryptonEffect.xnb` file.  I'm aware that MonoGame doesn't have XNA content processors, so I'm compiling the KryptonEffect.fx file in an XNA Content project.

When I try to load the `Effect`, I get an exception saying `The MGFX file is corrupt` in the `ReadEffect` method in MonoGame.  The header should be `MGFX` but it's a seemingly random byte array.

I then came across [this page](https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/wiki/Effects-And-Shaders) that says to use a tool named `2MGFX`.  I tried this, but the tool reports: `The effect must contain at least one technique and pass`.  From what I can see from [KryptonEffect.fx](https://preview.nuget.org/packagefiles/Krypton/2.0.0.0/Download?filePath=KryptonEffect.fx) the file, it does.

Has anyone got the Krypton Lighting Engine working on MonoGame for Windows 8? Or has anyone been able to load any kind of Effect file under Windows 8?

Comment: You actually want to know if anyone has gotten it working, or you want to know how to get it working yourself? You should be more specific about the troubles you're having getting it working yourself, so this doesn't turn into a discussion.

Comment: Hi Byte56, I'd like to know what I need to do to get it working, in particular, loading an Effect file.  I think they're related so didn't restrict it to one or the other.

Comment: I also had a similar experience with MonoGame not loading XNB effects well. There's actually a monogame-specific effects format you can use. I never bothered.

Comment: Tom Spillman is being a great help in resolving the issues with the  effect file from Krypton.  I think there's just one little issue to resolve now before it's compatible with MonoGame.  Will submit pull request when all resolved.

Comment: I managed to get both Krypton and Krypton shader compile for MonoGame Windows 8 platform. However, no light is currently rendered and I can only see the hulls in the Krypton sample. Still trying to figure out what might be causing this behavior.

Answer (score -1):

Change Content Processor To "MonoGame Effect".

Comment: Hello Hobir! Welcome to gamedev.stackexchange.com. :) I have an improvement proposal for your answer: Add more information! (Think of "why?" and "how?" to get something done)